# lie algebra cohomology

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, group-cohomology, obstruction-theory

Suppose that I have a semi-simple lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ and I have a linear map from a vector space $V$ to $\mathfrak{g}$. This map is surjective. Can I show that the corresponding map from $V$ to $G$, the corresponding lie group, is also surjective? The Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ is semisimple and I know it has trivial cohomology, then I have the intuition that I can extend the properties for the lie algebra to the lie group, since it has no obstruction. But this is only a intuition and I dont know how to do it precise

Comment: I'm not sure "corresponding map" here is well defined. If you mean composing with the exponential map then that will only be surjective if the exponential is already (which is not true in general although it is in the compact case).

Comment: That's what I meant, composition with the exponential map. Is it true for $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{so}(6)$?

Comment: Well that is a compact Lie algebra so its exponential map is surjective and thus yes. There is no need to discuss Lie algebra cohomology here though.